# if-else and method calls inside Ruby class initialize method

Tags: ruby, initialization

My code actually works, but I'm not sure if it's the proper way to do it. It's purpose is to allow modifying certain file only once a day. There's a lots of code, but it roughly looks something like this:

```
class Something
  def initialize
    if file_modified_today
      load_file
      #it loads variables from a file
    else
      @aaa = rand(1..30)
      # ... lots of other variable assignments
    end 
  end
  def file_modified_today
    #returns true or false
  end
  def load_file
    #reads and loads variables from a file
  end
end
```

I hope my code is not confusing. My question is, is this way of initializing class wrong? I could probably think of a way to remove if-else and method call from initialize, maybe define class method, and use it before creating instance

Comment: I don't find this to be a bad approach at all.  You should be doing that kind of logic in an initialize method vs. repeating the logic constantly for each variable.

Comment: Small unrelated comment: The convention when defining methods that returns `true` or `false` is to end with a questionmark: `file_modified_today?`

Comment: @Josh - that is nice to hear, I was having a feeling that it is wrong when I call methods "file_modified_today?" (thx @hirolau) and "load_file" **before** I finished initialization of class Something

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review and would be more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you exactly are trying to do. However, this it isn't the nicest way to `initialize` an object.

Why don't you try to create a class method instead?

```
class Something

  def initialize
    @aaa = rand(1..30)
  end

  def self.file
    if file_modified_today?
      load_file
    else
      new() # initialize a new object
    end
  end

  def self.load_file
    #reads and loads variables from a file
  end

  private

  def file_modified_today?
    #returns true or false
  end
end
```

However, you might what to consider a different approach. It seems that you only want to load a file if it is modified that day. You could handle that in the `#load_file` method. Which makes the `#file` method obsolete. So in that case, you can load a file if it is modified of create a new object.

```
load_file if file_modified_today?
```

Comment: I prefer the OP's solution. The initialize method should hold the logic of setting the objects variables initially.

Comment: @JanDintel, yes I mentioned in my OP that I could probably refactor my code with class method(s) ... Ruby has multiple ways of doing same thing so I often have doubts which way I should pick. Thanks